# You are not authorized to view this page is a dns issue?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am getting the following error while browsing my asp.net page deployed in IIS:

```
You are not authorized to view this page
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please try the following:

Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory or page. 
Click the Refresh button to try again with different credentials. 
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Technical Information (for support personnel)

Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search for the words HTTP and 401. 
Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Authentication, Access Control, and About Custom Error Messages.
```

Is this something regarding the issue with dns settings?

Comment: No, it is not a DNS issue.  What kind of authentication model are you using?

Comment: DNS is, to put it simply, a system that maps hostnames (like www.stackoverflow.com) to IP addresses (like 69.59.196.211). Once you've gotten far enough to get error messages from the server, you've found the server, and DNS is no longer relevant.

Comment: yea ,, now i am getting page not found error also..when i unticked the windows integrated authentication. is that a dns issue ?

Comment: are you browsing directly to a page, or are you expecting it to load some default page (i.e. www.yoursite.com/ vs www.yoursite.com/defaultpage.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 401 error is likely not a DNS issue itself; it simply means that, for some reason, the user is not authorized to view the page.  This could be because IIS cannot view the page, or because web application does not allow the current web user to view the page.

That said, it may be possible for DNS to still be the culprit.  If DNS is used as a piece of the authentication system (which, I believe, may be the case with Active Directory), and the server cannot correctly use DNS to do the resolution it needs to authenticate users, then yes, DNS probably cause a 401.

Comment: so what could be resolution here? if this is cause of active directory?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a DNS issue: if it was, the host could not have been found.

If you are using IIS, the authentication of the site is probably not set correctly.

Comment: i am using active directory retrieval into the website ..is that was an issue ?

Comment: yea ,, now i am getting page not found error also..when i unticked  the windows integrated authentication. is that a dns issue ?

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error is not DNS related.  It means that the account that IIS is running under (or the account being passed to it for authorization and authentication) does not have rights to execute the page.  It is more likely a security issue on the folder structure for your application.  Verify what account your site is running under, and that it has read rights in Windows to the root folder and subfolders.

Comment: yes it has ... read rights ...
now i am getting page not found error also..when i unticked the windows integrated authentication. is that a dns issue ?

Comment: Are you able to get to anything on that server? If so, it's not a DNS issue.